# update dell drivers on ubuntu 14.04 dell e5450

Tags: dell

The drivers package for dell e5450 for Ubuntu 14.04 is here:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/il/en/ildhs1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=03CD1

after downloading the package inside it says tat drivers compatible for Ubuntu 12.04

is it safe to install them on 14.04?

Ziv

Comment: No, the probably won't work on 14.04.

Comment: so is it problem with dell since they publish in the page that it is compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.
Do you know where I can get updated drivers for e5450?
I have a problem that sometimes when i type on the keyboard it is like I am holding they key(I am not) and they key is  being typed until I type another key.
This problem is driving me crazy

Comment: You do not need those "drivers". They are not even drivers, but mostly some configs. you can look into it. Firstly you need to install a video driver if you have some Nvidia or AMD adapter.

Comment: I have an intel card where can I get it?
How does it relates to the keyboard problem?

Comment: You do not need any drivers for Intel. Regarding the keyboard I will look into the Dell's pack.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has uploaded the drivers pack for Ubuntu 14.04.

It is at the same link. I think you can install it.

But I do not see anything that can help with the keyboard problem. Mostly there are Nvidia, bluetooth and Wi-Fi drivers.

They keyboard issue is probably a hardware one.

Comment: but in this link as I mentioned before it says for version 12.0.4 .
Are you familiar with any problem with keyboard as I mentioned?

Comment: It says 14.04. No, I don't know about this problem.

Comment: in the page it says 14.0.4 but inside the file xml configuration file it says 12.0.4 maybe I should ask dell